# Rails and devise - testing controller when signed in and signed out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, devise

So I want to test controller which is using devise.

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe ArticlesController do
  before(:all) { @article = FactoryGirl.create(:article) }

  sign_in_admin

  describe 'GET new' do
    let(:call_request) { get :new }

    before { call_request }

    context 'admin signed in' do
      it { is_expected.to respond_with :ok }
    end

    context 'admin signed out' do
      it { is_expected.to respond_with 302 }
    end
  end
end
```

I followed [this guide from devise wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-controllers-with-Rails-3-and-4-(and-RSpec)). So I created ControllerMacros module as you can see here:

```
module ControllerMacros
  def sign_in_admin
    before(:each) do
      @request.env['devise.mapping'] = Devise.mappings[:admin]
      @admin = FactoryGirl.create(:admin)
      sign_in @admin
    end
  end
end
```

And included it, and other needed things to rails_helper:

```
require_relative 'support/controller_macros.rb'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, type: :controller
  config.extend ControllerMacros, type: :controller
(...)
```

Here is admin factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :admin do
    email 'email@email.com'
    password 'password'
  end
end
```

But now I don't know how to sign out admin? As sign_in_admin is executing before each test, but I need to sign admin out for some of the tests. What is the best way to test this controller with signed in/out admin?

btw I'm kinda new to testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Devise provides some helper methods for testing, including login_user which takes a user, so you shouldn't need to create the sign_in_admin function. Also by using before(:all) at the top of the block, you've signed in the admin for the entire suite of specs.

Use before(:each) within the individual contexts that you want a signed_in_admin.

```
describe ArticlesController do
  describe 'GET new' do
    let(:call_request) { get :new }
    let(:admin_user) { FactoryGirl.create(:admin) }

    before { call_request }

    context 'admin signed in' do
      sign_in(admin_user)
      it { is_expected.to respond_with :ok }
    end

    context 'admin not signed in' do
      it { is_expected.to respond_with 302 }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Ruby says: lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:675:in `method_missing': undefined method `login_user' for RSpec::ExampleGroups::ArticlesController::GETNew::AdminSignedIn:Class (NoMethodError). Do I need to include it somewhere?

Comment: Sorry it should be sign_in, not login. I've edited my answer. You need to require rspec and include the test helpers in your spec helper. RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, type: :controller end You can read about the test helpers in the devise docs, https://github.com/plataformatec/devise, they're at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Better way is to close `before` action into a context. The contexts are **signed_in**, and **non-singed in**. So you can do something as follows:

```
  describe 'GET new' do
    let(:call_request) { get :new }

    before { call_request }

    context "signed in" do
      before { sign_in_admin }

      it { is_expected.to respond_with :ok }
    end

    context 'non-singed in' do
      it { is_expected.to respond_with 302 }
    end
  end
```